# Xpath: Everything between two elements in html

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to do an xpath to get the text of every node between two nodes but it's getting kind of tricky. The structure looks a little like this:

```
<table class="infobox biography vcard">
<p>
  <b>Mark Hamill</b>
  <span> was born in ...</span>
  <i> in the early 1980s he...</i>
  <a href="/some/place">Luke Skywalker</a>
</p>
<div class="toc">
```

And I need all the text inside that paragraph that happens to be between a table and a div and this is my query xpath so far:
`//table[@class="infobox biography vcard"]/following-sibling::node()[following-sibling::div[@class="toc"]]/text()`
It does not bring all the text from some tags, how can I achieve that?
Note: The p tag does not have any props but so some other p tags inside that document

Comment: Is there an url to go with this and are you open to also considering css with bs4?

Comment: Update html code to include more data. Or at least make the existing one more clear. Where is text located?

Comment: Please update your question in a way that your XPath resembles your html-code (now missing @class attributes in html), and show expected result.

Comment: Sure thing. The Url is a wikipedia article. The URL is this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Hamill

Comment: I just edited the html code and added a URL :) @Qharr

Comment: And yes, I could also consider bs4. 
@SiebeJongebloed I just added the url and the expected output would be all the text that's in between the P tags

Comment: you should change your html-example so that the table is closed and the div is closed. Now the example suggests the p is inside the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED:**

The [wiki-page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Hamill) has 2 p-elements between the table and the div, like this:

```
<table class="infobox biography vcard">
<!-- Content of table -->
</table>

<p>Here all kinds of mixed content</p>
<p>Here other kinds of mixed content</p>

<div class="toc">
<!-- Content of toc -->
</div>
```

To get all text in the p's between the table and the div use this XPath:

```
normalize-space(//p[preceding-sibling::table[@class='infobox biography vcard'] and following-sibling::div[@class='toc']])
```

The normalize space is only ment to fulfill your "the expected output would be all the text that's in between the P tags", but depending on your needs could also use

```
//p[preceding-sibling::table[@class='infobox biography vcard'] and following-sibling::*div[@class='toc']]//text()
```

If you want to have full control over what to use from those p's you could start with just getting the p's like this:

```
//p[preceding-sibling::table[@class='infobox biography vcard'] and following-sibling::*div[@class='toc']]
```

and loop through the mixed-content of those p's and maybe use XPath as well, to get what you need.

Comment: How did you run the first XPath in JS? I ran it in the console and it returns an empty string

Comment: In Oxygen Developer and using Saxon. Could you share the url, to see why you get een empty string?

Comment: I found the reason why you did not get any results. It was because there were 2 p's between the table and the div. I have changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: I queried with the first one and works like a charm, I tried the other two and I couldn't make it work, however, it solves my question, thank you so much :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want the biography you can use adjacent sibling combinators to get the 2 paragraphs next to the table using bs4. It is faster than xpath.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Hamill')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(' '.join([i.text.strip() for i in soup.select('.biography + p, .biography + p + p')]))
```

Comment: It almost works :( except for the fact that I'll be scraping more sites aside from this one. And some of them don't have two paragraphs, some of them have more. Is there a way to make this dynamic?

Comment: There is no one size fits all when it comes to web-scraping. If this is wiki based perhaps consider the python wiki api?

Comment: You can dynamically determine the number of sibling p tags but that doesn't mean they will all be ones that you want.

Comment: I tried this as well and it serves pretty good, even tho it's not an XPath itself it works pretty darn good. That's why I'm giving it an upvote instead of the right answer even though it is correct.

Comment: Thank you. I think you should find it faster than xpath but test it and see.